# Installing internet connection for a newcomer

Tags: wifi

I’m a long time Mac OS user and decided to use elementary OS as a learning experience about Linux. So I have literally zero experience with Linux before.

So, I installed the newest version of elementary OS on my MacBoon Air 2013. The immediate problem I encounter is that I cannot connect to my internet wifi. In “network settings”, I only have VPN and Proxy but nothing else.

I saw all kinds of solutions and understood that I needed some kind of driver. But I have no Ethernet and my phone cannot be used as a hotspot. So I do not have internet access from this computer at all.

But I do have another computer that can be used to download things from the internet and I also have a usb drive.

Can someone tell me how to proceed from here? I don’t want my Linux experience to be only a few minutes lol :) Thank you!

Edit: I saw some solutions here assuming that one has some kind of internet connection. I am wondering if there is a way to do this without any internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

The only answer I can see is to establish a physical connection to a router via an ethernet cable and then do bcmwl-kernel-source update in AppCenter. Do you not know someone with a router and ethernet cable who would let you connect? It only takes a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

That's quite a common issue with Broadcom adapters if that's what you have, but the solution is very simple. You should connect to the internet using your mobile phone and USB tethering and do `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`